# Wordpress Submit hidden input data as custom field (Payment Plugin)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

So, I got a payment plugin where some information is entered in an popup. 
The popup stores the input data in a hidden input on the payment page

In payments field I got this for the hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" class="" name="auth" id="auth" placeholder="" value="">
```

Via JS I put the value from the popup to the input hidden data, which definetly works!

Then I add an action:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'ccp_payment_update_order_meta' );

function ccp_payment_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
        update_post_data( $order_id, 'auth', sanitize_text_field($POST['auth']) ); 
}
```

Somehow after the submission of the checkout form the data ($POST['auth']) is empty.

Why is this happening?

How can I store the value right?

Comment: Just fixed it! Hidden input needs to be in an paragraph with class="form-row form-row-wide"

Comment: You can answer your own question (and earn points for it)!

Answer (score 0):

Got it sorted out. It need to be in an paragraph like that
`<p class="form-row form-row-wide"><input type="hidden" ...></p>`